# Check that a user has a valid login shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to find out a method to check if a user that is in `/etc/passwd` has a valid login shell.

I see that there is a file `/etc/shells` that contains the shells, but I have no idea how to check if the user has their shell pointed there.

Comment: What part of this question is causing you difficulty? The `passwd` file is a colon-delimited file that includes information about user shells. Unix has a variety of tools (`cut`, `awk`, etc) that can extract information from the file. What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i got stuck at using loops to iterate through every user's shell and then check if it belongs to the login shells

Comment: How would an ordinary user get an *invalid* shell? `chsh` doesn't let you select a shell that isn't in `/etc/shell`.

Comment: @chepner System users are usually added without going through `chsh` and use shells like `/bin/false` and `/sbin/nologin` to disable logins.

Comment: System users aren't ordinary users.

Comment: The OP didn't specify ordinary users only...?

Answer (score 2):

Use `getent` to access the users's password database.

Use `id` to check that the user exists.

Use `cut -d: -f7` to recover the user's default or login shell.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

u="$1"

if id "$u" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  s="$(getent passwd "$u" | cut -d: -f7)"

  if [ -n "$s" ] && grep -qwF "$s" /etc/shells; then
    printf 'User %s has a valid shell %s\n' "$u" "$s"
  fi
else
  printf 'Unknown user %s\n' "$u" >&2
fi
```

Or corrected syntax of [@niry 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59008172/7939871)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while IFS=: read -r u _ _ _ _ _ s; do
  grep -qwF "$s" /etc/shells && v=' ' || v='n in'
  printf '%s has a%svalid shell\n' "$u" "$v"
done </etc/passwd
```

- The whole `while` loop receives `stdin` from `/etc/passwd`.
- The `IFS` separator is set to `:` to split fields.
- `read -r u _ _ _ _ _ s` is reading user field 1 in `u`, trash fields 2 to 6 in placeholder variables `_` and shell in field 7, with `-r` to not mess with backslashes.
- `grep -qwF "$s" /etc/shells` will check that the raw string of the shell `$s` is contained in `/etc/shells`. (`-q`: no output, `-w`: match only whole words, `-F`: match plain raw string)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I normally do it in my scripts.

```
danesh@hades:/tmp$ env | grep LOGNAME
LOGNAME=danesh

danesh@hades:/tmp$ getent passwd $LOGNAME | cut -d: -f7
/bin/bash

danesh@hades:/tmp$ getent passwd danesh | cut -d: -f7
/bin/bash

danesh@hades:/tmp$ getent passwd nobody | cut -d: -f7
/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Hope that helps.